# Date column remove decimal

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-formatting

How to remove the `.0` from the date column?

Table Name: persons

```
SNo  Name   Date 
1.   John    2015-04-30 00:00:00.0
2.   Mike    2013-04-30 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You select a timestamp column and didn't specify in which format it has to be displayed. So Oracle implicitly chose the format based on [NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams132.htm#REFRN10131). So, if you want your own format, use the [TO_CHAR()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function. **Example :** `TO_CHAR(MYTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`.

Comment: This format is most probably applied by your SQL client when *displaying* the values. Check the manual of your SQL client if you can configure the formatting of timestamp columns

Comment: What is the data type of your "date" column?  An Oracle `date` doesn't have fractional seconds so it's unlikely that your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` would try to append seconds.  Are you storing the data in some form of `timestamp`?  As a `varchar2`?  Something else?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SQL you're executing and the definition of the table (column names and data types). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer would depend on the **DATA TYPE** of the column.

If it is DATE or TIMESTAMP then to display in your desired format, then use **TO_CHAR** along with proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

```
SQL> select systimestamp, to_char(systimestamp,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                             TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAM
---------------------------------------- -------------------
30-JAN-15 01.42.01.851000 PM +05:30      01/30/2015 13:42:01

SQL>
```

Ideally the data type should be `DATE/TIMESTAMP` as per the **business requirement**. However, if you have a bad design and if you are storing it as string, then use `SUBSTR` to get the desired output.